# Laravel - redirect to page and scroll to the bottom of the page

Tags: php, redirect, laravel, scroll

Im using Laravel framework and in my controller I have

```
return Redirect::route('home');
```

which is redirecting to homepage. But I would like to accomplish the page to be scrolled down to see footer when redirecting. Something like `href="home#footer"` Is there a way for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate the URL for the route then append the hash and redirect to that url

```
$url = URL::route('home') . '#footer';
return Redirect::to($url);
```

Comment: What if I want to trigger the modal after redirecting ? Any idea ?