# Auto Scroll to Section Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

How to make the auto scroll to the section in laravel 4.2?

if in html, it can be done like this:

```
<a href="#contentA">A</a>
<div id="contentA">AAAAA</div>
```

what about in laravel?

//controller.php

```
Route::get('content#contentA', function(){
    return View::make('content');
});
```

//content.blade.php

```
<div id="contentA">AAAAA</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - redirect to page and scroll to the bottom of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472069/laravel-redirect-to-page-and-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-the-page)

Answer (score 5):

Generate the URL for the route then add **#your_section** with it and redirect to that url

```
$url = URL::route('mypage') . '#content';
return Redirect::to($url);
```